# Combine date and text values in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=07b02e21b9c7f2c4055940e0dbf68ed2)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    stock_date DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    inbound_date DATE,
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO inventory
(stock_date, product , inbound_date, quantity
)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01', 'Product_A', '2020-01-01', '100'),
('2020-01-02', 'Product_A', '2020-01-01', '100'),
('2020-01-03', 'Product_A', '2020-01-03', '250'),

('2020-01-01', 'Product_B', NULL, '500'),
('2020-01-02', 'Product_B', NULL, '500'),
('2020-01-03', 'Product_B', NULL, '500');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
product     |  last_inbound_date_01  |  last_inbound_date_03  |     quantity   |
------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------|--
Product_A   |      2020-01-03        |         2020-01-03     |       250      |
Product_B   |                        |           N/A          |       500      |
```

---

In the column `inbound_date` I have `NULL` values in the database. 
In this case I want to type in `N/A` in the results. 
Therefore, I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
iv.product AS product,
MAX(iv.inbound_date) AS last_inbound_date_01,
(CASE WHEN MAX(iv.inbound_date) IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE MAX(iv.inbound_date) END) AS last_inbound_date_02,

SUM(iv.quantity) AS quantity
FROM inventory iv
WHERE iv.stock_date = '2020-01-03'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

This query works without any issue in **[MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d9b31cc348d3e3cfc796d8965dd1e25e).** 
However, in `postgresSQL` I get error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "N/A"
LINE 5: (CASE WHEN MAX(iv.inbound_date) IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE MAX(...
```

Is it possible to combine `date values` and `text values` in one column in `postgresSQL` and if yes how do I have to modify the query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date to a string:

```
SELECT iv.product AS product,
       MAX(iv.inbound_date) AS last_inbound_date_01,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(iv.inbound_date) IS NULL
             THEN 'N/A'
             ELSE MAX(iv.inbound_date)::text
        END) AS last_inbound_date_02,
       SUM(iv.quantity) AS quantity
FROM inventory iv
WHERE iv.stock_date = '2020-01-03'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I would, however, recommend that you keep the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The absolutely only way to this is to convert it to a text string? My issue is that I further use the data in an Excel spreadsheet and it is quite unfortunate when they arrive as text and not in date format since some Excel formuals need the values as date. In MariaDB it was great to have a date-formated column that could also be filled with text values for further handling in Excel.

Comment: Yes, you can return NULL instead of the text N/A and preserve the date type. Remember, all the rows in a col must have the same datatype.